# Double select usernames in one query

Tags: mysql

I have three tables: `User_table`, `Message_table` and `Message_table_to`.

**User_table fields:**

user_id

username

**Message_table fields:**

message_id

author_id

message_text

message_time

**Message_table_to with this fields fields:**

message_id

author_id

user_id

I need everything from the `message_table` and the name `Username` from `author_id` and `user_id`. How is it possible to get both `usernames` from the `user_table` with one query?

**Notes:** I tried the following query:

```
$sql = "SELECT u.user_id, u.username, p.message_id, p.message_text,     p.message_time, p.author_id, k.message_id, k.user_id 
    FROM User_table u, Message_table p, Message_table_to k
    WHERE 
    k.message_id = p.message_id
    AND p.author_id = u.user_id
  ORDER BY k.message_id DESC 
 LIMIT 5
    ";
```

But I get only the username of the `p.author_id` and not the username from the `k.user_id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to join the `user_table` twice using alias in order to get user names for sender and recipients. I also changed the query to use explicit joins instead of where criteria:

```
SELECT u1.user_id, u1.username as sender, p.message_id, p.message_text,     p.message_time, p.author_id, k.message_id, k.user_id, u2.username as recipient 
FROM User_table u1
INNER JOIN Message_table p ON p.author_id = u1.user_id
INNER JOIN Message_table_to k ON k.message_id = p.message_id
INNER JOIN User_table u2 ON k.user_id=u2.user_id
ORDER BY k.message_id DESC 
LIMIT 5
```